# Is there a way to clone / copy the configuration of a Linux machine easily and quickly?

Tags: virtual-machine, settings

I frequently use a variety of Linux Virtual Machines (usually but not always with the same Linux distro) and I am wondering if there is a way to automate the configuration of these machines.

I always need Node.js installed, Python3 installed, Emacs installed, and would like a certain few configuration files to remain the same.

I use different cloud providers at different times, so using something like Amazon AWS' AMI images will not always work.

The route that I was going to take was just to have a massive `.sh` file that would do this for me, but I wanted to see if there is a more frequently used way to do this.

Does anybody have a specific technique to do this that they can share?

Note: If I had to zero-in on one distribution it would be Ubuntu, although I was hoping to have a distribution independent way to do this.

Because different distros use different package managers, this is a bit tricky for me to figure out.

Comment: There is a lot of ways but this depends on the distro you're using! So... can you try to answer that first to us?

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini edited

Answer (score 0):

Why not put all you configure in  github. And write a install.sh to apply it. So that you can get or put it anywhere